# initializing objects once in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have `WCF` service that is hosted in `IIS`.

I need to initialize once several things that will exists through all calls to the services.

Where  is the appropriate place to make those initializations ?

Thanks for assistance .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use constructor (either that of BaseService or actual service class) to initialize these properties

Bear in mind that when WCF service is configured for Per-Call instance mode, Service instance will be created for each client request

If is not strictly needed don't use any Singleton strategy:

Singleton WCF services should hardly ever be used- Singletons are the enemy of scalability! They only make sense in weird scenarios- logging to a single file, a single communications port or hardware device.

Comment: Actually this I want to do , create on file for logging and one DB object .

Comment: it will be hard to manage the synchronization between threads especially for DB operation

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize them in static constructor or using Container's with Lifetime manager.

[Singleton Per Call Context (Web Request) in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151201/singleton-per-call-context-web-request-in-unity)

Answer (score 1):

If your WCF service is configured to use ASP.NET Compatibility Mode, then just initialize them in Application_OnStart in Global.asax.