# WCF, Unity and per request lifetime

Tags: wcf, unity-container

In my WCF service I use Unity to resolve my services and their dependencies.

When registering types I want to give some types the lifetime of the request. Is there any well known and "correct" implementations of a PerRequestLifetimeManager?

Comment: There are several. I use some code from [Andrew Oakley's Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/atoakley/2010/12/29/unity-lifetime-managers-and-wcf/). `UnityOperationContextLifetimeManager` should suite your needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Singleton Per Call Context WCF Web Request in Unity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919872/singleton-per-call-context-wcf-web-request-in-unity)