# Resolution of the dependency failed, running task in ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, task

I need to run a heavy code parallel to other code so that user don't have to wait .. I am trying `Task.Run(() =>` to accomplish my task. My task is calling method from service using dependency injection.
I am getting following error:

> {"Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   \"Company.CacheProvider.CacheEmployeeProvider\", name =
>   \"(none)\".\r\nException occurred while: while resolving.\r\nException
>   is: InvalidOperationException - The PerRequestLifetimeManager can only
>   be used in the context of an HTTP request. Possible causes for this
>   error are using the lifetime manager on a non-ASP.NET application, or
>   using it in a thread that is not associated with the appropriate
>   synchronization
>   context.\r\n-----------------------------------------------\r\nAt the
>   time of the exception, the container was:\r\n\r\n  Resolving
>   Company.Provider.CacheProvider.CacheEmployeeProvider,(none)\r\n 
>   Resolving parameter \"cache\" of constructor
>   Company.Provider.CacheProvider.CacheEmployeeProvider(Company.Provider.Interface.IEmployeeProvider
>   provider, Company.Provider.Interface.ICache cache)\r\n    Resolving
>   Company.Provider.CacheProvider.RequestCache,(none) (mapped from
>   Company.Provider.Interface.ICache, (none))\r\n"}

Error is providing the possible reason .. but I am not able to find the solution ..

Entire application is using `PerRequestLifetimeManager` .. how can I use it in may task .. or how can I make my task run in different context without any issue ..

**UPDATE : - Registration**

```
 var container = new UnityContainer();   

 container.RegisterType<IEmployeeProvider>(new InjectionFactory(unity => unity.Resolve<CacheEmployeeProvider>(new DependencyOverride(typeof(IEmployeeProvider), unity.Resolve<DbEmployeeProvider>()))));       
 container.RegisterType<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();

 DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
 DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc.UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
```

Here is the base code of `EmployeeController`

**Dependency**

```
[Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Dependency]
public Lazy<IEmployeeService> EmployeeService { get; set; }
```

**Post Request**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddEmployee(EmployeeModel model)
{
   var employee = EmployeeService.Value.Add(model);

   Task.Run(() => SetupEmployeeArea(employee.Id)); //task to setup employee related data

   return RedirectToAction("EmployeeList"); //redirect user to the list of employees
}
```

**Task**

```
async Task SetupEmployeeArea(int id)
{
   EmployeeService.Value.EmployeeSetup(id); //this call firing exception
}
```

I also tried following , but this code is not executing completely .. while debugging I lost the pointer in middle and nothing happening.

```
async Task SetupEmployeeArea(int id)
{
   var employeeService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IEmployeeService>();
   employeeService.EmployeeSetup(id); //not getting any exception and code is also not running
}
```

Please share suggestions ... or if possible please also share best alternates to fulfill my requirement (run heavy code parallel) except "Hangfire" .. I already have too much load on that :)

Comment: Can you show the registration of EmployeeService?

Comment: @john added, please see update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the http context closes before the task is completed. Try to make the controller's method async and run the task like:

```
await Task.Run(() => SetupEmployeeArea(employee.Id)); //task to setup employee related data
```

Then the task finishes before the http context is closed.

If you would like to return a result before the task is finished consider using some background worker for this like QueueBackgroundWorkItem https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-background-processes-in-asp-net/ or some external framework like Hangfire and register your dependency to be resolved outside the http context.

If there is no need for some services to be resolved inside the http context change it scope to another e.g. transient or singleton https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647854.aspx. You can always create custom lifetime manager that handles cases when the http context is closed like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4698138/9502162.

Another approach is to load the page and then use ajax call to perform this task so then users will see the page immediately. But with this approach you make client app responsible for setting employee related data which may be unwanted.

Comment: can you please share some useful links?

Comment: Background worker (no Hangfire): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-background-processes-in-asp-net/

Async controllers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Ajax requests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186083/making-a-simple-ajax-call-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: To perform an ajax call I have to pass all the required parameter to the redirected view ... I have millions of users .. what can be the best way to pass parameters without clashing the users data

Comment: You only need employeeId for SetupEmployeeArea. I've added suggested solution to the answer

Comment: no that was just an example .. I need to pass a model

Comment: but as you suggested .. I am trying to prepare sample using background worker

Comment: so have you tried changing scope of those services or implementing custom lifetime manager? I edited the answer and this may help

Comment: thanks arekzyla .. trying to implement .. will update you ASAP.

Comment: Hello arekzyla . .thank you so much for your time and help .. I personally liked background worker solution, and will explore on my own . but for now the team has decided to setup a new hangfire server for this particular task. .. I will implement your solutions and will update all on this thread.

Comment: I'm glad I could help